# Kotlin function which counts standard deviation

Tags: statistics, kotlin

Here is the code. The code should counts the standard deviation for double array, but also for Int arrays.

```
fun calculateSD(numArray: DoubleArray): Double {
var sum = 0.0
var standardDeviation = 0.0

for (num in numArray) {
    sum += num
}

val mean = sum / numArray.size

for (num in numArray) {
    standardDeviation += Math.pow(num - mean, 2.0)
}

val divider = numArray.size - 1

return Math.sqrt(standardDeviation / divider )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to be more idiomatic when working with collections, for instance:

```
import kotlin.math.pow
import kotlin.math.sqrt

fun sd(data: DoubleArray): Double {
    val mean = data.average()
    return data
        .fold(0.0, { accumulator, next -> accumulator + (next - mean).pow(2.0) })
        .let { sqrt(it / data.size )
    }
}
```

BTW, I don't think that `data.size - 1` is correct

Comment: There are two kinds of standard deviation. The [sample standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation) involves dividing by _N_ - 1.

Comment: True: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction . Do you think that this is the case here ?

Comment: You could complain about unclear naming or lack of documentation for this function, but I'd hesitate to call it "wrong".

Comment: `data.sumOf { (next - mean).pow(2) }` instead of `aggregate` is simpler, but requires kotlin 1.4.

Comment: Did you mean "instead of fold" ?

Answer (score 1):

### Performance

Something to consider (in general) is whether `Math.pow(x, 2.0)` is going to be optimized by the interpreter/compiler into `x * x` or not. The former can be slower if, say, it is computed as `Math.exp(Math.log(x) * 2.0)`.